# Higher current or higher voltage from a power supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current

When choosing a power supply, it is generally suggested that the voltage should be the same as the device rating but the current to be <= of the power supply unit (PSU.) The reason for the latter is typically - “although there’s more current available, the device only draws or takes in as much as it needs.”

Questions:

1. What is not clear to me is how come this doesn’t apply to voltage as well, since, for example, more voltage indicates more pressure/force and hence more current but why can’t the device still limit by drawing only the necessary current?
2. In case of input voltage being the same as the device rating, how does the device manage to draw only required current? Assuming that the resistance in the device is the same, shouldn’t more current from the power supply also pass through the device unobstructed?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site :-) This question is essentially asking for tuition/discussion on the very basics of electronics, page 1 stuff. It's a Q&A site, rather than discussion forum, and can't be a personal tutorial service, which is effectively what you're asking for. You'll find mountains of information detailing the relationship between voltage and current in a DC circuit freely available on the internet for you to research and learn from. Voting to close for those reasons, I'm afraid.

Comment: To add to the above comment, question 2 talks about some abstract device, when in reality every different device out there has its own particular construction and behavior, which may vary based on its usage and is certainly not modeled by just a "resistance". Trying to cover everything from a light bulb to an integrated amplifier would be far too broad.

Comment: I upvoted the question because there are many situations involving non-linear (non-resistive) loads, where the answer is not so obvious or trivial.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of ratings: One is what the device *does*. The other is what the device is the *maximum capability* or limiting conditions within which the device is able to properly perform its thing.

Most power supplies are **voltage** sources so the voltage rating is what the device *does*. The current rating is the supply's *maximum capability*. The voltage source will supply the rated voltage within specification so long as the resulting current does not exceed the current rating.

For the much rarer **current** source, the current rating is what the device *does* while the voltage rating is what it is capable of. The current source will provide the rated current within specification so long as the voltage required to do so does not exceed what the supply is capable of.

The vast majority of the time you will run into a current source is a voltage source that has a current limiting featured. When the current drawn from the source has exceeded a set limit and the supply no longer attempts to hold the voltage constant and instead starts adjusting (reducing) the voltage to reduce the current and maintain it that set limit. If the current drawn falls below that limit then the supply starts maintaining the fixed voltage again.

So it needs to be understood that the voltage and current ratings for supplies do not have the same usage, and what they mean depends on whether the supply is designed to be a voltage supply (a voltage source) or a current supply (current source).

So your question is kind of like the following questions:

- How come a computer which is specified to run off 120VAC and can
  operate up to a maximum ambient temperature up to 40C, doesn't always
  cause the room to be 40C?
- If a person is able to run at 6km/h as long as they are carrying less than 10kg of load, how is it possible for them to run at 6km/h while carrying less weight?
- If a person can maintain a running speed of 8km/h for a maximum of an hour, how can they ever run for less than an hour?

You can see there that the question doesn't make any sense when you understand what the ratings are actually saying.

Comment: It should be emphasised to a beginner that in almost all circumstances the power supplies which a consumer or beginner will encounter are voltage sources. Current sources are exceedingly rare as modules to power devices.Though, of course it's a common pattern within the minutiae of individual circuits.

Comment: @Dannie Emphasized more than "most"?

Comment: It's a good answer, I gave it a +1. I just think most is a bit of an understatement. If you buy a PSU off any bits-n-bobs site or something with a nameplate, 99 times out of 100, at least, I'd say, would have constant voltage characteristics.

(Though you couldcorrectly argue that a current-limited constant-voltage source is also a voltage-limited constant-current source, or course. Though few people look at it like that).

Comment: @Dannie I've edited some stuff in. I hope it doesn't muddle the main point.

Comment: I think the examples are confusing and not really helpful or applicable to the OP's question. But I don't want to downvote.

Comment: The answer is good.  I agree that you can't just say that all power supplies are voltage sources -- because some (florescent light ballasts, anyone?) are constant-current or near-constant current, and you never know the point at which a beginner may be entering electronics.

Comment: @PStechPaul I thought it would help outline the logical clash to someone unfamiliar with voltage and current because my concern when I say something like "these terms aren't what you think they mean" to someone unfamilar with electricity, they might focus on the wrong thing (like what is the difference between voltage and current) when that's not really the crux of the issue. It's a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If the device was a resistor it wouldn't matter (assuming that the power supply maintains both limits)

Say you have a 12V 12W resistor, (perhaps it's a an essential oil heater), you could use a 1A power supply capable of more than 12V and the resistor would get 1A and the power supply would produce 12V. Alternatively  you could use as 12V power supply capable of more than 1A and the resistor would get 12V and the current would be 1A
these results due to Ohm's law.

However most consumer electronics is more complex than that.  most devices want a fixed voltage and will take a current up to their label current the current they want is not a fixed value but instead varies depending on what parts inside the device are operating or not.

There are however some consumer devices that want a fixed current instead (most of them are some sort of LED illumination)

The repeaters used in under-sea fibre-optic cables are also current fed, they wire them all in series and feed a fixed current into one end of the cable, so all the repeaters see the same current, typically it takes thousands of volts to push this current through the cable.

Answer (score -1):

I had originally posted this as a comment, but I think it is really more of an answer.

The answer is obvious for a device that is essentially resistive, where there is a linear relationship between applied voltage, resistance, and current. It is a little more complicated for something like a voltage regulator into a fixed resistance, in which case the current will remain just about the same over a range of applied voltage. And for a switching power supply, the current drawn will have an inverse relationship to applied voltage, and power will remain essentially constant.

This also applies to some extent to a motor, where a constant load will result in less current drawn at higher voltage. This is why some power tools with series wound (universal) motors can burn up if used with a long extension cord of insufficient capacity, where the higher voltage drop results in the motor drawing more current to get the power needed, and will overheat.