# How do power adaptors provide adjustable current to devices?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ohms-law

Power adaptors usually have a fixed voltage (i.e 6 volts) and a maximum available current (i.e 1 ampere.) A device can draw as much current as it needs up to the maximum amount the adaptor provides.

I can't fully understand how this works so lets use an example, DC is a 6 volt 1 ampere adaptor:

[image]

This is how I currently understand it working, is it correct?

Power supply is pushing 1 ampere to the circuit at all times, it's the job of the resistor here to limit the current to what the rest of circuit needs, in this case I=V/R = 6/1000 = 6mA. A power supply can push an infinite amount of current, the resistor here makes sure the output is always 6mA.

I've read power supplies usually have a sophisticated circuit to change their internal resistance to make all this happen which goes against my above paragraph. If this is true then how can they tell the required amperage?

Comment: No, not correct. Also did you search about this already, similar questions already exist and have been answered.

Comment: No, no, no, and also no.

Comment: Power supplies that "change their internal resistance" do so to limit current in the event the load tries to pull more current than the supply can safely provide. They do their best to act as constant voltage sources otherwise. Unless you're referring to *current* sources, which are rare and only used for very particular things.

Comment: `Power supply is pushing 1 amp to the circuit at all times` ... no ... the power supply generates a voltage difference between its output pins ... it is this voltage difference that pushes current through the connected load

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Power supply is pushing 1 amp to the circuit at all times.

There's your misunderstanding.

Most power supplies are constant voltage. The load determines how much current is drawn. If the load increases (lower resistance) then the voltage will start to drop, the voltage sensing  circuit will detect this and turn on the output transistor a bit more to bring the output voltage up to the desired value.

If the load doesn't require the full rated power supply current then the PSU delivers less.

This is exactly the same as you switching on a light bulb in your house which is connected to the national grid which can supply thousands of amps. Why does your lamp not draw all the current from the grid?

---

Update following some of the comments:

Most electronic power supplies will have a built-in current limiting circuit. If the supply is rated for 6 V, 1 A I would expect that this should be the minimum guaranteed output and that it may even maintain 6 V at 1.1 or 1.2 A. After that, if the load resistance is decreased further the PSU will go into current limiting mode and the output voltage will start to decrease. With a dead short across its output you will have 0 V and a current determined by the current limiting circuit.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/626050/higher-current-or-higher-voltage-from-a-power-supply/626059#626059

Comment: I see, so the power supply "adjusts" its internal resistance based on `V = I.R` to make sure `V` is always 6 volts, and `I` is whatever my circuit is using which in this example is 6 mA. This adaptor can support up to 1 amp which means my circuit resistor can go as low as 6 ohms. If I put a 5 ohm resistor there (I = V/R = 6/5 = 1.2 A) it's Armageddon, it's similar to shorting the circuit with no resistor, right?

Side note, Why does my lamp not draw all the current from the national grid? I actually like to know.

Comment: @Dan No adjustment is needed unless you insist on modelling it as a current source--which is much more involved than just modelling it as a voltage source.

Comment: @Dan are you asking about series linear regulators specifically or contstant voltage power supplies in general? What you're describing has some similarity to how a series linear regulator works, but there are many other kinds of power supplies that work with different mechanisms.

Comment: @Dan National grid: You know Newton's equal and opposite reaction? The voltage drop developed across the load opposes the source voltage in the same way. "*If I put a 5 ohm resistor*" No, not shorting at all.  The voltage source is not ideal which is why it does not have a current capability of infinite to begin with. It cannot maintain voltage within spec above that current and so the output voltage droops.

Comment: So you are saying "self adjusting an internal resistor" is one way to do it but it's not the usual way. However, my understanding is now correct, the lowest resistor I can use is 6 ohms? I need to ask one more thing, when doing I=V/R  = 6/1000 = 6ma, why do I not need to take the adaptor's resistance into account? does it not have any resistors in its circuit, why do I only take my own resistance into account?

Comment: @Dan "*Why do I not need to take the adaptor's resistance into account? does it not have any resistors in the circuit?*" It's already accounted for in the rating when they say the supply can provide up to 1A of current while having the output voltage remain within +/-5% of rated. What do you think is causing that voltage drop up to 5% as the current supplied increases? It is not necessarily a straight, constant resistance either due to behaviour of components like transistors. But the 5% tells you worst case at the limits.

Comment: I see, so the "resistor inside the adaptor" has already reflected it's effect on my `V` value, so when I do V/R = 6/1000= 6mA I don't need to add adaptors internal resistance to my own resistance, that value has already been taken care of to output 6 volts, hope I make sense here.

Comment: @Dan Correct. Remember it's not supplying 6V, it's supplying 6V +/- some percent. It is not necessarily a straight, constant resistance either due to behaviour of components like transistors. The voltage sag/droop might not be linear with increase in current as it would be with a constant internal resistance (actually impedance since it varies with frequency of the current waveform being supplied via Fourier). But the 5% tells you worst case at the limits.

Comment: And finally, how does my AC lamp NOT draw all the current provided by the city grid? is there a similar mechanism provided by my fuse box or out in the street somewhere?

Comment: @Dan You know Newton's equal and opposite reaction? The voltage drop developed across the load by the current flowing through it opposes the source voltage in the same way.

Comment: @Dan Your lamp is a resistor. A resistor has a(n approximately) constant *resistance*, which means if you put a given voltage across it (say 120 V, the voltage of the grid where I live), you get a certain current through it (say 0.5 A, for a typical 60 W incandescent). This is simplifying out some details (modern lamps with CFLs or LED bulbs are significantly more complicated, and even incandescents have strong temperature related effects), but that's the gist of it.

Comment: @Dan There's a lot to be said about *why* resistors act that way (the Drude model is a decent introduction), but in general you can treat that as a definition: a resistor has a certain resistance, and that resistance imposes a fixed proportionality between the voltage across and current through the resistor.

Comment: Can I ask how does a AA battery achieve the same thing? A fresh 1.5v AA battery is said to be able to provide up to 1 Amp.  How does it achieve the `up to` part? How does it not push all its 1 Amp to my resistor (then become 1.5/1000 = 1.5 mA)  if I hook it up to my circuit? I guess i still doesn't get what entity is "regulating" the `up to` part of all this! or perhaps there is no regulation going on!? the regulator IS my resistor. it's MY resistor who decides how much current it wants. The lower it goes the more current it receives given a fixed voltage.

Comment: If so then my original assumption in the question IS correct, I just didn't' word it correctly. The power adaptor doesn't have a magical changing resistor inside it. If I short out my circuit it will push all it's amperage to my circuit (all the 1 amp). It's the duty of MY resistor to limit that current, all my power adaptor is doing it keeping the voltage constant. `V` is always 6 volts, `R` is the resistor I choose in my circuit. `I` then will change by itself based on ohm's law, adaptor is doing nothing on that part.

Comment: @Dan, see the update.

Answer (score 3):

> Power adaptors usually have a fixed voltage (i.e 6 volts) and a maximum available current (i.e 1 amp). A device can draw as much current as it needs up to the maximum amount the adaptor provides.

Yes

> I can't fully understand how this works so lets use an example, DC is a 6 volt 1 amp adaptor:

> This is how I currently understand it working, is it correct?

> Power supply is pushing 1 amp to the circuit at all times ...

Nooooo!<sup>1</sup> Up to 1 A is available, but the supply is providing 6 V to the circuit.

> ... it's the job of the resistor here to limit the current to what the rest of circuit needs, in this case I=V/R = 6/1000 = 6mA. A power supply can push an infinite amount of current, the resistor here makes sure the output is always 6mA.

This type of power supply provides 6 V. As long as the load current is below its maximum (in this case 1 A), it manages to keep 6 V on its terminals. The resistor then draws the current dictated by Ohms Law, I = V/R, I = 6V/1k = 6 mA.

> Tho I've read power supplies usually have a sophisticated circuit to change their internal resistance to make all this happen which goes against my above paragraph. If this is true then how can they tell the required amperage?

They don't "change their internal resistance" as such. There are various methods they can use to control their output, switch-mode, linear regulators, don't get too confused about the actual mechanism. If they have some sort of output current awareness, for limiting, or shutdown, or constant current, then they usually have a small value series resistor (maybe 100 mΩ, maybe smaller) and sense the voltage across it to determine what the output current is. Then they can control their voltage output, or their power output, or their current output (different supply architectures do different things), to control the output current to a set point. That set point could be 1 A, or much less than 1 A in the case of overload (for foldback designs), or there's no set point and let's hope there's a fuse on the output while it's delivering several amps into an overload.

[1] Or YES. If you have bought a constant current driver, for instance to drive LEDs. A typical specification might be "drives 300 mA into any voltage load from 0 to 24 V". This is a specially controlled supply (almost invariably switch-mode) that instead of providing a constant voltage, where the load's resistance governs the current up to a maximum, it provides a constant current output where the load determines the load voltage up to a maximum. There's no reason why such a supply shouldn't have an adjustable output current.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your comments, you (OP) said:

> The power adaptor doesn't have a magical changing resistor inside it.

But the power adaptor does have a "magical changing resistor" inside it! Let's see what this "magic" is with the help of a simple electrical experiment. It is so simple that it could have been carried out in the middle of the distant 19th century (for example, by Ohm and Thevenin:-) without knowing what a "transistor" or "negative feedback" is. We can call it a "man-controlled power adapter".

To make it, we need only four elements - a simple voltage source V, a variable resistor R (rheostat) in series, a voltmeter at the output and, of course, someone willing to turn the resistor wiper. Ok, I agree to do it for free and with pleasure:-)

We can load the "adapter" by another variable resistor RL (another rheostat) in series to R. I assume you don't mind turning its wiper? If so, let's get started…

At first glance, this arrangement does not make much sense because it turns out that we simply decrease a voltage through the voltage divider R-RL. But when you decrease the load resistance RL, I will start decreasing my resistance R (and vice versa, when you increase RL, I will start increasing R) until the voltmeter reading is restored.

As a result of this "magical changing", you have the illusion that the "adaptor" resistance is zero. In fact, only its "differential resistance" is zero, and its "static resistance" is what it is.

This begs the question, "Why should there be such a resistance inside the adapter that only reduces the input voltage?" The trick is to initially reduce the output voltage so that we can then both increase and decrease (ie regulate) it. The same trick is used in amplifiers where the output voltage is  initially decreased two times (as they say, "biased") and then is "magically changed" between the supply rails.

In real power adapters and amplifiers of this analog type, the role of this "magical changing resistor" is performed by a transistor.

---

With this story I wanted to not only explain how to make a constant voltage source using the principle of negative feedback but also show the power of simple circuit concepts through an intuitive explanation.

If this approach appeals to you, you can find many such circuit stories in my [Circuit Idea](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea) wikibook and my [Circuit Stories](https://circuitstories.blogspot.com/) blog.